# Error on build android command in ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried to run this command:

```
ionic run android
```

and i got this error:

> :processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :processDebugResources
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/WriteNow/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:57:
>   AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/jdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1 Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the
>   stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 3.261 secs
>
> Error: /home/ubuntu/workspace/WriteNow/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/WriteNow/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:57:
>   AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/jdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1 Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the
>   stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please include the content of your `config.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sebaferreras! I had an unnecessary line in the xml file.

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed the issue :)

Comment: Which line did you remove? Please post the solution that worked for you.